# Qt, OpenCv Statically Compiled Executable Still Contains Dependencies

Tags: c++, qt, static, dependencies, static-libraries

I am trying to use Qt Creator to build a standalone executable which uses Qt and OpenCv - so I'm attempting static compilation. I built a static version of Qt. I built a static version of OpenCv. I set my Qt version to the statically built version. I set my build kit to this new static build. In my .pro file, I put...

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv-build\install\include

CONFIG += static

LIBS += C:\opencv-build\lib\libopencv_core320.dll.a
LIBS += C:\opencv-build\lib\libopencv_highgui320.dll.a
LIBS += C:\opencv-build\lib\libopencv_imgcodecs320.dll.a
LIBS += C:\opencv-build\lib\libopencv_imgproc320.dll.a
LIBS += C:\opencv-build\lib\libopencv_features2d320.dll.a
LIBS += C:\opencv-build\lib\libopencv_calib3d320.dll.a
```

But when I attempt to start the resultant .exe, I receive the following error:

The procedure entry point _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE4findEPKcjj could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll

I used Dependency Walker to analyze the exe: apparently it still requires tons of dlls(including libopencv_core320.dll and KERNEL32.DLL (but no Qt libraries), for example). What am I doing wrong? I followed all the steps listed [here](http://dimitris.apeiro.gr/2015/06/24/build-a-static-qt5-for-windows-by-compiling/%22here%22). This is my first time attempting a static build, so I'm unclear on how to further troubleshoot this.

Comment: My crystal ball says that your compilers runtime library and the C++ standard library are amongst your non-static dependencies. Why not just ship the required libraries as part of your program and have its installer/package install them? In the long run that's probably going to be easier (and what most programs *do*) than building and maintaining a completely static executable.. just my 2 cents.

Comment: System DLLs like Kernel32 and ntdll cannot be statically linked. This wouldn't be desirable even if it were possible as it would pin your program to only working on a single version of Windows.

Comment: If I was linking against some library statically I would make sure that library was actually built statically. And usually on Windows the static library represented by *.lib and maybe separate *.obj files and not some derivatives of *.dll e.g. dll.a. Or at least that was the story when I did quite a lot of Windows platform development.